# Need spacing for the board component

Tags: vaadin

There are two issues open to fix the problem with spacing the board component.

Has anyone faced the same requirement and found an easy as possible workaround?

The Links to the open issues:

https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/616

https://github.com/vaadin/board/issues/92

Comment: The first link contains a workaround.  Have you tried it? How has it failed?